# Swift 2 array of tuples not working as in swift 1

Tags: swift, swift2

Array:

```
var rows: [(title: String, body: String, icon: String, iconColor: UIColor)] = []
rows.append(title: "Foo", body:"Bar", icon: "Bas", iconColor: UIColor(netHex: 0x4285f4))
```

the append line is giving me following error since I upgraded to swift 2:

```
Cannot invoke append with argument list of type (title: String, body: String, icon: String, iconColor: UIColor)
```

in swift 1 it was working fine. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: argument list of type what...?

Comment: @Fogmeister updated Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the parameters list, not the tuple itself: you're missing a pair of `()`.

```
rows.append((title: "Foo", body:"Bar", icon: "Bas", iconColor: UIColor(netHex: 0x4285f4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, OK, you need more parentheses.

At the moment you're providing a list of 4 parameters.

You need one tuple parameter like this...

```
rows.append((title: "Foo", body:"Bar", icon: "Bas", iconColor: UIColor(netHex: 0x4285f4)))
```