# Swift cannot invoke append with an argument of type (name: String, String)

Tags: string, swift, list, append

I get the error

Swift cannot invoke append with an argument of type (name: String, String)

I have attached part of my code here.

```
func gotData(result:NSDictionary){

    if result.count == 0{
        print("data is nil")
    }else{

        if result["Search"] == nil{
            print("no results found")
            Global.showAlert("No Movie Found", message: "Double check the name", view: self)
        }else{
            var results = result["Search"] as! [NSDictionary]

            for result in results as [NSDictionary]{
                var name = result["Title"] as! String
                var year = result["Year"] as! String
                var imdbID = result["imdbID"] as! String

                self.movieList.append(name:"\(name), (\(year))", imdbID:"\(imdbID)")
            }
            tableView.reloadData()



        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs on this line

```
self.movieList.append(name:"\(name), (\(year))", imdbID:"\(imdbID)")
```

Anyone have any Idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Probably something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654654/swift-2-array-of-tuples-not-working-as-in-swift-1 (just a guess)

Comment: what is element type of self.movieList?

Comment: @EricD. seems to work. I don't know why exactly, but it does. And thats good. Thanks.

Comment: because type of element in your self.movieList is tuple

Comment: You're welcome. Suggestion: accept the "vote to close as duplicate". That way future readers will see that the two questions were similar, it can help them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the line like this

```
self.movieList.append((name:"\(name), (\(year))", imdbID:"\(imdbID)"))
```

made it work. Thank you @EricD